# Laravel Sum transactions amount grouped by category

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to sum all transactions and group these records by category with the summed value of transactions for a particular month.

Example (Current month):

```
Groceries => 500
Subscriptions => 100
Coffee => 0
```

But the current code I have only groups categories when a transaction has occurred for that month and will return the following:

```
Groceries => 500
Subscriptions => 100
```

Here are my the following database tables:

**Transactions table:**

| id | date | category_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 300 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 2020-06-06 | 3 | 100 |

**Categories table:**

| id | display_name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Groceries | Food |
| 2 | Subscriptions | Subscriptions |
| 3 | Coffee | Coffee |

And my code that selects transactions for the current month but doesn't return a full list of categories even if there are no transactions.

```
$currentMonth = date('m');

$grouped = DB::table('categories')
  ->join('transactions', function ($join) use ($currentMonth) {
    $join->on('transactions.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
      ->whereRaw('MONTH(date) = ?',[$currentMonth]);
    })
  ->groupBy('categories.display_name')
  ->selectRaw('sum(transactions.amount) as sum, display_name as name')
  ->pluck('sum', 'name');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join, and use a left join:

```php
$grouped = DB::table('categories c')
    ->leftJoin('transactions t', function ($join) {
                $join->on('t.category_id', '=', 'c.id')
                $join->on(DB::raw('MONTH(t.date) = ?'))
            })
    ->groupBy('c.display_name')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(t.amount) AS sum, c.display_name AS name')
    ->setBindings([$currentMonth])
    ->pluck('sum', 'name');
```

The raw MySQL query I am suggesting here is:

```sql
SELECT
    c.display_name,
    SUM(t.amount) AS sum
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN transactions t
    ON c.id = t.category_id AND
       MONTH(t.date) = ?
GROUP BY
    c.display_name;
```

The structure used above in the left join is critical here, because it ensures that every category on the left side of the join would appear in the result set, even if it have no matching transactions for a given month.